# Using strconv for negative hex values in Go

Tags: hex, go

I've  been building an assembler for no good reason the past day or so using Go so I can get familiar with the language. It's my first real program using Go so I expected problems, but I have a consistent bug coming up time and time again. I just figured out other hacky ways to fix it in other cases, but this time I think I need an answer so I feel like I'm actually doing this right.

Basically, I have to parse tons of byte values. Some of these are signed bytes so -1 = 0xFF and so on. When calculating the address of a label I need to find the offset of it from the current address. The following code is a stripped down basic version of what I  use to get the offset:

```
//  lbladdr holds the target label address
//  address holds current address in memory
//  label[x] holds the offset
if address > lbladdr {
    lbladdr -= address
}
label[x] = strconv.FormatInt(int64(lbladdr), 16)
```

This works for positive values, but when I get a negative address (address > lbladdr) then instead of getting a value like FE I get -2. I don't get why the standard library would append a negative sign to a hex number and I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation about it. I've looked a lot of other places but I can't seem to find anyone with the same problem either.

I hope it's just something on my end that is a simple fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's by design: http://golang.org/src/pkg/strconv/itoa.go?s=628:668#L8

What you may want is to cast to uint64:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    i := -1
    fmt.Printf("%x\n", uint64(i))
    fmt.Println(strconv.FormatUint(uint64(i), 16))
}
```

Comment: That's a fairly simple fix which is perfect. I completely forgot that Go was open source and that I could just look at what was happening. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's perfectly reasonable to use a negative sign on hexadecimal numbers. I know that when working with assembly it's common to use the actual bitpattern for the register you are representing in hex to represent the signs. However Go doesn't know you are doing that. Neither is go's formatting function written to support hex values as they would be in a CPU register. Further the bitpatterns will differ depending on the register size (16 vs 32 vs 64 and big vs little endian). you would be storing them in. So the base isn't enough to print them the way you want. You will need to write your own formatting lib that supports formatting for the type of Register you want to represent.